# LinkedList implementation in Typescript

Tags: typescript, linked-list

I am currently learning data structures and I am facing several problems when trying to implement LinkedList in TS. I added several methods but though it seems to work, the output is really weird.

My questions are in comments.

My code:

```
function LinkedList () {     //why doesn't fat arrow syntax work??
                             //ie. let LinkedList = () => {...this.append = () => {}...} 
                            // prints out TypeError: t.append is not a function

let Node = (elem) => {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.next = null;
}

this.head = null;
this.len = 0;

this.append = (elem) => {

    let node = new Node(elem);
    let current;

    if(this.head === null){
        this.head = node;
    } else {
        current = this.head;
        while(current.next){
            current = current.next;
        } 
        current.next = node;
    }
    this.len++;
}

this.removeAt = (pos) => {
    if(pos > -1 && pos < this.len){
        let current = this.head;
        let previous;
        let index = 0;

        if(pos === 0){
            this.head = current.next;
        } else {
            while(index++ < pos){
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            previous.next = current.next;
        }
        this.len--;
        return current.elem;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}


this.insert = (elem, pos) => {
    if(pos > -1 && pos < this.len){
        let current = this.head;
        let index = 0;
        let previous;
        let node = new Node(elem);

        if(pos === 0){
            node.next = current;
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            while(index++ < pos){
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            node.next = current;
            previous.next = node;
        }
        this.len++;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

this.toString = () => {
    var current = this.head;
    var str = '';
    while(current){
        str += current.elem; //output is undefinedundefinedundefined
               // str += JSON.stringify(current); 
               // prints out {"next":{"next":{}}}{"next":{}}{}
        current = current.next;
    }
    return str;
}

}

let t = new LinkedList();
t.append('asd');   //Doesn't work with fat arrow function declaration
t.append(1);
t.append(0);
console.log(t);
let tt = t.removeAt(1);
console.log(t,'tt', tt);
t.insert('asd',2);
let ttt = t.insert('a', 1)
console.log(ttt);
console.log(t);
console.log(t.toString());
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use classes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to me you're mixing ES5-like syntax (where people use functions to create JavaScript's pseudo-classes) with TypeScript. You do not need to do that. Write correct typescript instead, otherwise there's no reason to use TypeScript at all.

Also be careful with fat arrow function syntax. The reason why they exist is not to replace functions. In your case there's zero real reason why you would need to use it. In fact, that's what's probably breaking your code: they're using your original (global?) scope as the scope of `this` inside the functions, *not* the LinkedList instance itself.

A more correctly idiomatic implementation of what you're trying to do would look something like this:

```
class Node {
    private elem;
    private next;

    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    private head = null;
    private len = 0;

    public append(elem) {
        let node = new Node(elem);
        let current;

        if (this.head === null) {
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            current = this.head;
            while (current.next) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = node;
        }
        this.len++;
    }

    public removeAt(pos) {
        if (pos > -1 && pos < this.len) {
            let current = this.head;
            let previous;
            let index = 0;

            if (pos === 0) {
                this.head = current.next;
            } else {
                while (index++ < pos) {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
                previous.next = current.next;
            }
            this.len--;
            return current.elem;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public insert(elem, pos) {
        if (pos > -1 && pos < this.len) {
            let current = this.head;
            let index = 0;
            let previous;
            let node = new Node(elem);

            if (pos === 0) {
                node.next = current;
                this.head = node;
            } else {
                while (index++ < pos) {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
                node.next = current;
                previous.next = node;
            }
            this.len++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public toString() {
        var current = this.head;
        var str = '';
        while (current) {
            str += current.elem; //output is undefinedundefinedundefined
            // str += JSON.stringify(current); 
            // prints out {"next":{"next":{}}}{"next":{}}{}
            current = current.next;
        }
        return str;
    }
}

let t = new LinkedList();
t.append('asd'); // Works fine
t.append(1);
t.append(0);
console.log(t); // LinkedList
let tt = t.removeAt(1);
console.log(t, 'tt', tt); // LinkedList, 'tt', 1
t.insert('asd', 2);
let ttt = t.insert('a', 1)
console.log(ttt); // true
console.log(t); // LinkedList
console.log(t.toString()); //asda0
```

But since there's no type annotation anywhere, it serves little purpose. At the very least, Node need to be annotated so you can have more stable code.

As a bonus: `console.log()` will not convert your LinkedList instance to string because it can display objects properly. Instead, `toString()` is only automatically used when JavaScript has to convert it down to string. So this would work:

```
console.log(t + ""); //asda0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Can you be more specific about annotations (node) ?

Comment: Your code is in TypeScript, but it's not enforcing [types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) of any kind. You will get autocompletion, but it's still too dynamic; you're not going to have it enforce any rules on you. For example, for a LinkedList, it would make sense to use it use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), so you would only be able to add objects of a certain type to the list. The efficiency of type-strict languages comes from using these type of constructs.

Comment: I think author needs to study OOP first. The fact that he uses "function" for creating data structure shows the author does not know. Typescript/javascript are very similar to c++/c/java when it comes to create data strcuture usnig OOP.

Comment: The next declaration in the Node class needs to be public, so that we could access it when we assign it to the current declaration in the LinkedList class.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more "TypeScripty" implementation with generics and strict typings. Note that I'm also returning an Node and not a node's content when removing the node.

```
class LinkedNode<T> {
    private _elem: T;
    public next: LinkedNode<T> | null;

    constructor(elem: T) {
        this._elem = elem;
        this.next = null;
    }

    get elem(): T {
        return this._elem;
    }
}

class LinkedList<T> {
    private head: LinkedNode<T> | null = null;
    private len = 0;

    constructor(headElement?: LinkedNode<T>) {
        this.head = headElement || null;
    }

    public append(elem: T) {
        let node = new LinkedNode(elem);
        let current: LinkedNode<T>;

        if (this.head === null) {
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            current = this.head;
            while (current.next) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = node;
        }
        this.len++;
    }

    public removeAt(pos: number): LinkedNode<T> | null {
        if (pos > -1 && pos < this.len && this.head) {
            let current = this.head;
            let previous: LinkedNode<T> = current;
            let index = 0;

            if (pos === 0) {
                this.head = current.next;
            } else {
                while (index++ < pos && current.next) {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
                previous.next = current.next;
            }
            this.len--;
            return current;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public insert(elem: T, pos: number) {
        if (pos > -1 && pos < this.len && this.head) {
            let current = this.head;
            let index = 0;
            let previous = current;
            let node = new LinkedNode(elem);

            if (pos === 0) {
                node.next = current;
                this.head = node;
            } else {
                while (index++ < pos && current.next) {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
                node.next = current;
                previous.next = node;
            }
            this.len++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public toString() {
        var current = this.head;
        var str = '';
        while (current) {
            str += current.elem;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Link {
  value: number;
  nextNode: Link;

  constructor(nodeValue: number, nodeReference: Link) {
    this.value = nodeValue;
    this.nextNode = nodeReference;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  list: Link;
  _length: number = 0;

  insertLink(nodeIndex: number): boolean {
    if (this.list == null) {
      this.list = new Link(nodeIndex, null);
      this._length++;
      return true;
    } else {
      let temp = this.list;
      while (temp.nextNode != null) {
        temp = temp.nextNode;
      }
      temp.nextNode = new Link(nodeIndex, null);
      this._length++;
      return false;
    }
  }

  printLinkList(): void {
    let temp = this.list;
    if (this.list == null) {
      console.log('empty linked list');
    } else {
      while (temp.nextNode != null) {
        console.log(temp.value);
        temp = temp.nextNode;
      }
      console.log(temp.value);
    }
  }

  searchNodeByValue(i: number): number {
    let temp = this.list;
    let counter = 1;
    let position = null;
    if (temp == null) {
      console.log('empty list');
    } else {
      while (temp.nextNode != null) {
        if (temp.value === i) {
          position = counter;
        }
        counter++;
        temp = temp.nextNode;
      }
      //check if the  last element of the node
      if (temp.value === i) {
        position = counter;
      }
    }
    //console.log(position);
    if (position == null) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return position;
    }
  }

  removeListItemByValue(i: number): boolean {
    if (this.list == null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      let itemPosition = this.searchNodeByValue(i);
      if (itemPosition == 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        let temp = this.list;

        //if its the first element in the stack
        if (itemPosition == 1) {
          this.list = this.list.nextNode;
          return true;
        }

        //if the element is not first or last
        while (temp.nextNode.value != i) {
          console.log('in here');
          temp = temp.nextNode;
        }
        temp.nextNode = temp.nextNode.nextNode;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  removeListItemByPos(idx: number): boolean {
    let temp = this.list;
    let counter: number = 1;

    if (idx > this._length) return false;

    if (idx == 1) {
      this.list = this.list.nextNode;
      return true;
    }

    while (counter != idx - 1) {
      temp = temp.nextNode;
      counter++;
    }
    temp.nextNode = temp.nextNode.nextNode;
  }

}

const linkedList = new LinkedList();
linkedList.insertLink(1);
linkedList.insertLink(2);
linkedList.insertLink(3);
linkedList.insertLink(4);

linkedList.removeListItemByPos(4);
linkedList.insertLink(5);

linkedList.printLinkList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation

```
export class Link<U> {
    private value: U;
    next: Link<U> | null;

    constructor(value: U) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    getValue(): U {
        return this.value;
    }
}

export class LinkedList<T> {
    private list: Link<T> | null;

    constructor()
    constructor(link: Link<T>)
    constructor(link: Link<T>, list?: LinkedList<T>)
    constructor(link?: Link<T>, list?: LinkedList<T>) {
        if (!link) {
            this.list = null;
        } else {
            this.list = link;
        }
        if (list) {
            this.list.next = list.list;
        }
    }

    add(value: T): void {
        let current = this.list;
        if (!current) {
            this.list = new Link<T>(value);
        } else {
            let link = new Link<T>(value);
            link.next = current;
            this.list = link;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My Implementation is this:

```
class LinkNode { 
    constructor(public data: any, public next: LinkNode | null = null) { }
}

class LinkList { 
    private head: LinkNode | null = null;
    constructor() { }


    get size(): number { 
        let node = this.head;
        let counter = 0;

        while (node) {
            counter++;
            node = node.next;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    get firstNode(): LinkNode | null { 
        return this.head;
    }

    get lastNode(): LinkNode | null { 
        let node = this.head;

        while(node && node.next) 
            node = node.next

        return node;
    }

    insertFirst(data: any) { 
        return this.head = new LinkNode(data, this.head);
    }

    insertLast(data: any): LinkNode { 
        let node = new LinkNode(data);
        if (!this.lastNode) return this.head = node;
        return this.lastNode.next = node;
    }

    removeFirst(): LinkNode | null { 
        return this.head = this.head ? this.head.next : null;
    }

    removeLast(): any { 
        let node = this.head;
        if (!node) return;

        while (node.next) {
            if (!node.next.next) return node.next = null; 
            node = node.next;
        }

    }

    clear() { 
        return this.head = null;
    }

    getAt(index: number): LinkNode | null {
        let node = this.head;
        if (!node) return null;

        for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) { 
            if (!node.next) return node;
            node = node.next; 
        }
        return node;
    }

    get allElements(): string[] { 
        let node = this.head;
        const arr: string[] = [];

        while (node) { 
            if (node.data) arr.push(node.data);
            node = node.next;
        }
        return arr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my thought:

```
class Link<T> {
    private value: T;
    public next: Link<T> | null;

    constructor(elm: T, next = null) {
        this.value = elm;
        this.next = next;
    }

    getElem(): T {
        return this.value;
    }


}

class LinkedList<T> {
    private head: Link<T> | null = null;
    public len = 0;

constructor(headElm?: Link<T>) {
    this.head = headElm ?? null;
}

appendFirst(elm: T) {
    this.head = new Link(elm, this.head);
    this.len++;
}

appendLast(elm: T) {
    let current: Link<T>;
    const node = new Link(elm);

    if (this.head === null) {
        this.head = node;
    } else {
        current = this.head;
        while (current.next) {
            current = current.next;
        }

        current.next = node;
    }

    this.len++;
}

insertAt(elm: T, index: number) {
    if (index > this.len) {
        return;
    }

    if (index === 0) {
        this.appendFirst(elm);
        return;
    } else if (index === this.len || index === -1) {
        this.appendLast(elm);
        return;
    }

    let currentIndex = 0;

    let current: Link<T> = this.head;

    let previous: Link<T>;

    while (currentIndex < index) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
        currentIndex++;
    }

    const node = new Link(elm, current);

    previous.next = node;

    this.len++;
}

removeFirst() {
    this.head = this.head.next;

    this.len--;
}

removeLast() {
    let current: Link<T> = this.head;

    let previous: Link<T>;

    while (current.next) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    previous.next = null;

    this.len--;
}

removeAt(index: number) {
    if (index >= this.len) {
        return;
    }

    if (index === 0) {
        this.removeFirst();
        return;
    } else if (index === -1 || index === this.len - 1) {
        this.removeLast();
        return;
    }

    let current: Link<T> = this.head;

    let nextNode: Link<T>;

    let prevNode: Link<T>;

    let currentIndex = 0;

    while (currentIndex < index) {
        prevNode = current;

        current = current.next;

        nextNode = current.next;

        currentIndex++;
    }

    prevNode.next = nextNode;

    this.len--;
}

getList() {
    let current = this.head;

    while (current) {
        console.log(current.getElem());

        current = current.next;
    }

    console.log('_____________');
}
}

const node = new Link(130);

const list = new LinkedList(node);

list.appendFirst(10);

list.appendLast(20);

list.appendLast(90);

list.appendLast(30);

list.appendLast(70);

list.getList();

list.removeAt(3);

list.getList();
```